# Pre-filing phrase to use

Tags: pre-fiiling, terninology

Iwould like to note in one of my documents that I imntend to file a patent for a specific item I am, sending an invoice to a customer for. I know I can't say "patent pending" - is there another acceptable term that would indicate it is exclusively our design?

Thank you

Comment: Better indicate the country in which you are based. Also add the following tags "confidentiality agreement", "disclosure" and "commercial use". Are you selling the product already? If it is widely distributed, it might be too late.

Answer (score 1):

One would hope that your contract with them makes the ownership of IP clear. But putting that aside:

**[Proprietary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proprietary)**

> 1:  one that possesses, owns, or holds exclusive right to something
>
> 2:  something that is used, produced, or marketed under exclusive legal right of the inventor or maker; specifically :  a drug (as a patent medicine ) that is protected by secrecy, patent, or copyright against free competition as to name, product, composition, or process of manufacture

You might say that your design is proprietary, or that the products you have provided to them include proprietary designs.

Answer (score 0):

**Confidential**

Why?

Because you don't only want them to know it's yours, you want them not to publish it, else it wouldn't be novel anymore and therefore not patentable.

---

Seriously, if you just write propietary or exclusive or this is our IP, that does not tell them they have to keep it secret, so they might, not in bad faith, publish it as part of a product brochure or whatever. And then your possibility for a patent is gone.

Comment: Just writing confidential doesn't accomplish much if you don't have a valid confidentiality agreement in place.